# How to transpose the data in r

Tags: r

I have read similar headings and unfortunately couldnt find an answer. The problem is that i have the following data:

```
            [,1]            [,2]         [,3]       [,4]   [,5]         
HomeTeam "Arsenal"        "Leicester" "Man United" "QPR"  "Stoke"      
AwayTeam "Crystal Palace" "Everton"   "Swansea"    "Hull" "Aston Villa"
```

and i want it to be as follows:

```
                   Teams       Opponent 
HomeTeam         Arsenal Crystal Palace  
AwayTeam  Crystal Palace        Arsenal   
HomeTeam1      Leicester        Everton   
AwayTeam1        Everton      Leicester   
HomeTeam2     Man United        Swansea     
AwayTeam2        Swansea     Man United
```

i have tried the following command but its incorrect, just to give you an idea what i am trying to do:

```
odd <- seq(1, 759, by = 2)
even <- seq(2, 270, by = 2)
df <- data.frame(team = df_1[odd,1], 
                  opponent = df_1[even,1])
```

Question is: how can i modify the command above ? Or can u suggest me any other code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: See command `t`. Also `??transpose` would have given you the answer to "how to transpose data?".

Comment: @VincentGuillemot The format requested by the OP is not a simple transposition. There are a few more operations to be considered to obtain the desired output.

Comment: @RHertel: you are absolutely right, that is why I wrote it as a comment and not an answer. ;)

Comment: I would also like to ask the OP if such a complicated transformation of the original data is really necessary: the final result looks really messy to me. (or should I say Messi?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have this:

```
m <- structure(c("Arsenal", "Crystal Palace", "Leicester", "Everton", 
"Man United", "Swansea", "QPR", "Hull", "Stoke", "Aston Villa"
), .Dim = c(2L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("HomeTeam", "AwayTeam"
), NULL))
```

You can obtain your result with:

```
res<-cbind.data.frame(Teams=c(m),Opponent=c(m[2:1,]))
rownames(res)<-make.unique(rep(c("HomeTeam","AwayTeam"),ncol(m)),sep="")
#                   Teams       Opponent
#HomeTeam         Arsenal Crystal Palace
#AwayTeam  Crystal Palace        Arsenal
#HomeTeam1      Leicester        Everton
#AwayTeam1        Everton      Leicester
#HomeTeam2     Man United        Swansea
#AwayTeam2        Swansea     Man United
#....
```